# Calling a suspend function from legacy library on background thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, hivemq

I'm using the HiveMQ Android Client in my Android App. I "probe" for a device using a transient object for the transaction, which wraps an `Mqtt3AsyncClient`.

```
fun probe(callback: ((String) -> Unit)) {
    ...
    client
        .connectWith()
        .cleanSession(true)
        .keepAlive(60)
        .simpleAuth()...applySimpleAuth().send()
        .whenComplete { _, _ ->
            client
                .subscribeWith()
                .addSubscription().topicFilter(eventTopic).applySubscription()
                .callback { message ->
                    handleMessage(message.topic, message.payloadAsBytes))
                }
                .send()
                .whenComplete { _, _ -> attemptToCommunicate()}
        }
}
```

The problem is that my `handleMessage` function (which will run async because that's what the async client is all about) makes a call to a `suspend fun` in it's body, e.g.

```
fun handleMessage(topic:String, message:Bytes) {
    ...
    saveDataFuncThatIsDefinedWithSuspend(...)
    ...
}
```

I can't exactly mark `handleMessage` as `suspend`, because it's call from the callback will be an error. Marking the `probe` function as suspend doesn't solve that either. And I'm not at liberty to not use the HiveMQ client, so I'm stuck with the callback.

I toyed with wrapping the suspend function as such:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { saveDataFuncThatIsDefinedWithSuspend(...) }
```

but I got the impression, that this is considered a bad idea? Or I could wrap a `runBlocking` around it, but again, that seems frowned upon. Should I make my transient transaction object itself a CoroutineScope implementor? I'm struggling with how one bridges these two worlds in a case like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in most cases you will want to define a new `CoroutineScope` as a child of another scope, and not create a new scope out of the blue.

That said, you can always pass in a scope as a parameter (to `probe` and/or `handleMessage`) so that you can use it like this:

```
scope.launch { 
    saveDataFuncThatIsDefinedWithSuspend(...)
}
```

That scope should be created somewhere outside of your legacy code where you have access to a parent scope, for example in a suspend function (possibly the one that calls `probe`).

Comment: Interesting. I guess I didn't realize that passing scopes as parameters would be ok. Kinda felt like a bad thing. I don't know why. I think I could actually do that in this case though.

Comment: Usually you don't need it because the coroutine scope is implicitly passed to a function when it is marked as a `suspend` function. When you cannot use the `suspend` modifier, or if you do not want to wrap the entire body of the function in that scope, it is perfectly ok to pass the scope as a parameter. The standard lib even contains a good example for a function that is marked as `suspend` *and* has a `CoroutineScope` parameter. The function `kotlinx.coroutines.flow.stateIn` is declared as: `public suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.stateIn(scope: CoroutineScope): StateFlow<T>`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I believe is the one situation on Android where `runBlocking` is an appropriate solution. If you cannot design a blocking version of your suspend function, there’s no way you can avoid tying up two threads for this (one from the coroutine dispatcher, and the one the client library that waits for it). So `runBlocking` is the simplest, cleanest way to achieve this.

If your message handler doesn’t need to wait for your suspend function to return, then it does make sense to `launch` a coroutine to call it. But doing this with a one-off CoroutineScope that you create and abandon the reference for is an anti-pattern. Either you want to launch the coroutine globally so it doesn’t automatically get cancelled under some event like navigating away from a related screen or you don’t. For a global coroutine like the first case, you would use GlobalScope, and for the second case you would use a scope tied to the relevant lifecycle for whatever you’re doing.

Comment: So to clarify... for this case, if I want to not block the legacy async library thread with my suspend call, GlobalScope is actually the guy to use (rather than making a new one), since it's just a one shot invocation?

Comment: Yes, if you don’t want to wait for it, and you don’t mind launching it and forgetting about it. There are cases where this would be considered a resource/memory leak, which is why you see a compiler warning when you use GlobalScope. Kind of annoying that they put the warning in and you have to use an annotation to turn it off whenever you use GlobalScope. But I guess it makes it clear then that you a) wanted it to be global and b) already considered that this means the coroutine will run to completion without being tied to a finite scope.